# Composable loses ui state if when app goes to the foreground and item is not the visible on the screen

Tags: android, android-jetpack-compose

when the app goes to the background and the foreground is gone the non visible message from the conversation lose the voted Value but if the message was visible before going to background the value will be saved this also happen if the screen is turn off

```
@Composable
private fun IncomingAnswer(message: AnswerMessageReceived, messageAction: MessageAction) {
    Text(text = message.text, style = C.Typography.body2)
    Row {
        if (message.questionID != null) {
            var voted by rememberSaveable {
                mutableStateOf<Boolean>(false)
            }

            ChatIconButton(
                modifier = Modifier.padding(top = Dimens.size_6x, bottom = Dimens.size_6x, end = Dimens.size_3x),
                contentDescription = "vote up",
                isEnabled = voted.not(),
                hasActiveLook = true,
                iconID = com.x.y.c.R.drawable.ic_thumb_up_24,
            ) {
                voted = true
                messageAction.onVoteUp(message)
            }
        }
    }
}
```

the voted rememberSaveable return to false
it can be replaced with a value in the AnswerMessageReceived data class but i think rememberSaveable should be able to handle this case

Comment: what you meant by "the non visible message from the conversation", not just that overall your question is not very clear, please add more context